# Display a list of values from an array on a grid drawn using pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to create a small program that will draw a 6 x 6 grid. I have an array of values (36 elements) which I want to display in each box. I'm able to draw the grid using the below code, however I'm not able to figure out how to display the text from the array in each box. Later I want to check where the current selected box is and determine if it has a particular value and perform some action based on it.

`

```
matrix = ["1", "0", "0", "P", "2", "0",
          "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0",
          "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0",
          "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0",
          "0", "0", "0", "0", "4", "3"]
```

I want to show the values from matrix array in the grid

```
class Grid:
    def __init__(self, width, height, rows, cols):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.rows = rows
        self.cols = cols

    def draw(self, screen):
        # draw the grid

        for i in range(self.rows):
            for j in range(self.cols):
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), (i * self.width, j * self.height, self.width, self.height), 1)

def show_grid():
    pygame.init()
    screen_width = 500
    screen_height = 500
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Text Adventure Game")
    grid = Grid(50, 50, 6, 6)
    player = Player(0, 0, 50, 50, (255, 127, 0))
    running = True
    while running:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    player.move("up")
                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    player.move("down")
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    player.move("left")
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    player.move("right")
        screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
        grid.draw(screen)
        player.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.update()

    pygame.quit()
```

```
class Player:
    global steps
    steps = 0

    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.color = color

    def draw(self, screen):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.color, (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height))

    def move(self, direction):
        if direction == "up":
            if self.y > 0:
                self.y -= self.height
                steps = steps - 50
                print(self.x, self.y)
        elif direction == "down":
            if self.y < 250:
                self.y += self.height
                print(self.x, self.y)
                steps = steps + 50
        elif direction == "left":
            if self.x > 0:
                self.x -= self.width
                print(self.x, self.y)
        elif direction == "right":
            if self.x < 250:
                self.x += self.width
                print(self.x, self.y)
```

`

I want to populate the grid with the values from the matrix array and perform actions based on the values

Answer (score 0):

```
def print_matrix(matrix):
    for i in range(len(matrix)):
        if i % 6 == 0 and i != 0:
            print('')
        print(matrix[i], end = ' ')
    print('')

print_matrix(matrix)
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.